# SQL Server : Cross Join in GreenPlum (Pre-LATERAL version of Postgres)

Tags: sql-server, greenplum

I'm attempting to convert the following SQL Server query into a GreenPlum version of the query:

```
INSERT INTO #TMP1 (part_id, file_id, location, measure_date)
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        pt.part_id, qf.file_id, qf.edl_desc, pt.measure_date
    FROM 
        part pt WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN 
        file_model qm with (nolock) on qm.file_model_id = pt.file_model_id
    INNER JOIN 
        file qf with (nolock) on qf.file_id = qm.file_id;

INSERT INTO @part_list (file_id, part_id, measure_date)
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        t1.file_id, k.part_id, k.measure_date
    FROM 
        #TMP1 t1 WITH (NOLOCK)
    CROSS APPLY 
        (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (300) 
             t2.part_id, t2.measure_date
         FROM 
             #TMP1 t2 WITH (NOLOCK)
         WHERE 
             t1.file_id = t2.file_id and t1.location = t2.location
         ORDER BY 
             t2.measure_date DESC) k
WHERE 
    t1.measure_date >= dateadd(day, 30, getdate());
```

The idea here being that the final table contains the most recent up to 300 parts for all parts programs that are active (ie manufactured something) in the last 30 days.

Per [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472790/postgres-analogue-to-cross-apply-in-sql-server), I am aware that LATERAL JOIN would do it, except my organization is using an older version of Postgres that does not have LATERAL, so I was left with implementing the following function instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION BuildActiveParts(p_day INT, p_n INT)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD --TABLE (part_id bigint,file_id int, measure_date timestamp, location varchar(255)) 
AS $$
DECLARE
    part_active RECORD;
    part_list RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR part_active IN 
    SELECT DISTINCT qf.file_id, qf.location
    FROM part pt 
    INNER JOIN file_model qm  on qm.file_model_id = pt.file_model_id
    INNER JOIN file qf  on qf.file_id = qm.file_id WHERE pt.measure_date >=  current_date - p_day LOOP
        FOR part_list IN 
        SELECT DISTINCT pt.part_id, qf.file_id, pt.measure_date, qf.location
        FROM part pt 
        INNER JOIN file_model qm  on qm.file_model_id = pt.file_model_id
        INNER JOIN file qf  on qf.file_id = qm.file_id WHERE qf.file_id = part_active.file_id
        AND qf.location = part_active.location 
        ORDER BY pt.measure_date DESC LIMIT p_n LOOP
            RETURN NEXT part_list;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Later used in:

--Build list of all active programs in last p_day days.  This temporary table is a component of a larger function that produces a table based on this and other other calculations, called daily.
-- Note: this insert yields 'function cannot execute because it accesses relation'
    INSERT INTO TMP_part_list ( part_id, file_id, measure_date,  location)
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM BuildActiveParts(p_day, p_n) AS active_parts (part_id int, file_id text, measure_date timestamp, location text )
    ;
```

Unfortunately, this function is used in inserts to another table (an unavoidable reality of my business requirements), so while the function returns nice happy results when run in isolation, I get a big angry `function cannot execute on segment because it accesses relation` when I try to use it for its intended purpose.  While I've seen suggestions to the effect of "make a VIEW instead", that's not really an option because a view resulting from the script this functionality is a part of would take too long to query.

What can I do, beyond embarking on a months-long excursion through a jungle of red tape to convince my organization to update their stuff, to resolve this?

Edit: Here are some attempts based on comments:

Attempt with function, did not work because of `function cannot execute on segment because it accesses relation`:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS BuildRecentParts(TEXT, TEXT, INT);

CREATE FUNCTION BuildRecentParts(file_id TEXT, location_in TEXT, p_n INT)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD --TABLE (measure_date timestamp, part_id bigint) 
AS $$
DECLARE
    part_list RECORD;
BEGIN
        FOR part_list IN
        SELECT DISTINCT pt.measure_date, pt.part_id
        FROM part pt 
        INNER JOIN file_model qm  on qm.file_model_id = pt.file_model_id
        INNER JOIN file qf  on qf.file_id = qm.file_id 
      WHERE qf.file_id = file_id
        AND qf.edl_desc = location_in
        ORDER BY pt.measure_date DESC LIMIT p_n LOOP
          RETURN NEXT part_list;
    END LOOP;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT DISTINCT qf.file_id, qf.edl_desc, (SELECT  pti.measure_date, pti.part_id FROM part pti 
        INNER JOIN file_model qmi  on qmi.file_model_id = pti.file_model_id
        INNER JOIN file qfi  on qfi.file_id = qmi.file_id 
      WHERE qfi.file_id = qf.file_id
        AND qfi.edl_desc = qf.edl_desc
        ORDER BY pti.measure_date DESC LIMIT 300)
FROM part pt 
        INNER JOIN file_model qm  on qm.file_model_id = pt.file_model_id
        INNER JOIN file qf  on qf.file_id = qm.file_id 
WHERE pt.measure_date >=  current_date - 30 ;
```

Attempt without function, will not work because subquery has multiple columns:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TMP_TMP1 (part_id bigint, file_id varchar(255), location varchar(255), measure_date timestamp) DISTRIBUTED BY (part_id);

INSERT INTO TMP_TMP1 (part_id, file_id, location, measure_date)
    SELECT DISTINCT pt.part_id, qf.file_id, qf.edl_desc, pt.measure_date
    FROM part pt 
    INNER JOIN file_model qm  on qm.file_model_id = pt.file_model_id
    INNER JOIN file qf  on qf.file_id = qm.file_id;
ANALYZE TMP_TMP1;


SELECT DISTINCT t1.file_id, t1.location, (SELECT  t2.measure_date, t2.part_id FROM TMP_TMP1 t2
      WHERE t2.file_id = t1.file_id
        AND t2.location = t1.location
        ORDER BY t2.measure_date DESC LIMIT 300)
FROM TMP_TMP1 t1
WHERE t1.measure_date >=  current_date - 30;
```

I also attempted a recursive CTE, but found that that was unsupported.

Comment: The linked question's answers contains good examples how to emulate LATERAL on older versions. Did you try them? (i.e. put the sub-select / function call into a `SELECT` clause a.k.a. correlated subquery)

Comment: I did, that also gave me a "cannot execute because it accesses relation".  I'll edit in the attempt when I get a chance.

Comment: This may be another greenplum limitation then (other than LATERAL): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615211/function-cannot-execute-on-segment-because-it-accesses-relation -- *Functions in Greenplum are limited compared to Postgres. If a function access a "relation" (think table) you cannot call it in the select of another table.* -- Try the correlated subquery without using a function.

Comment: The subquery returns multiple columns, I don't think I can...

Answer (score 0):

Well, Greenplum doesn't have dirty reads so you can't implement the nolock hint you have.  That is probably a good thing too.  I would recommend removing that from SQL Server too.

I think the best solution is to use an Analytical function here instead of that function or even a correlated subquery which Greenplum supports.  It is also more efficient in SQL Server to use this approach.

```
SELECT sub2.part_id, sub2.location, sub2.measure_date
FROM    (
    SELECT sub1.part_id, sub1.location, sub1.measure_date, row_number() over(partition by sub1.part_id order by sub1.measure_date desc) as rownum
    FROM    (
        SELECT pt.part_id, qf.edl_desc as location, pt.measure_date
        FROM part pt
        INNER JOIN file_model qm on qm.file_model_id = pt.file_model_id
        INNER JOIN file qf on qf.file_id = qm.file_id
        WHERE pt.measure_date >=  (now() - interval '30 days')
        GROUP BY pt.part_id, qf.edl_desc, pt.measure_date
        ) AS sub1
    ) as sub2
WHERE sub2.rownum <= 300;
```

Now, I had to guess at your data because it looks like you could get into trouble with your original query if you have multiple qf.qcc_file_desc values because your original group by includes this.  If you had multiple values, then things would get ugly.

I'm also not 100% sure on the row_number function without knowing your data.  It might be this instead:

```
row_number() over(partition by sub1.part_id, sub1.location order by sub1.measure_date desc)
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed a spot while redacting names which will affect your evaluation.  Also, I don't see any component to your query which limits to parts manufactured within the last 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

Between answers here and from architects at my organization, we decided that we have struck a GreenPlum limitation that would be too costly to overcome, the logic that performs the Cross Join will be shifted to the R script that calls the stored procedure that this functionality would have been a part of.